# faking a httpcontext returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web, sitemap

I have been following different tutorials but all of them are returning null, code I have been  using is,

```
  public HttpContext SetNewHttpContext(string uRL)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", uRL, "");
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
        return new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }
```

I also tried

```
        public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext(string uRL)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", uRL, "");
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                                HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

        httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                    null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                    new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                    null)
                            .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

        return httpContext;
    }
```

but non of them actually works, i am calling this context using

```
 SiteMapProvider contentMapProvider = SiteMap.Providers["SPContentMapProvider"];
 SiteMapNode currentNode = contentMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(FakeHttpContext(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()));
```

it gives me error

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Scenario

I need HTTPContext of a different ASP.NET page(sharepoint) A in Another ASP.NET page B, when we are being navigated from Page A to Page B.